# How to clean and rebuild a projekt in netbeans when it does not resolve after an refactoring bug?

Tags: netbeans

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at rooconn.RooConnClient.tryConnect(RooConnClient.java:45)
    at rooconn.TestConnection.main(TestConnection.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - rooconn.system.FilePutRequestSimple is not abstract and does not override abstract method onServerStreamReady(java.io.InputStream,java.io.OutputStream) in rooconn.RooServerEvents
    at rooconn.Request.<clinit>(Request.java:25)
```

This exception is thrown when I run my project. The problem is, that roocon.system package does not exists anymore, it has been refactored to rooconn.client.

The package does not exists in:

- ".../src/rooconn/"
- ".../build/classes/rooconn/"
- ".../dist/RooConn.jar/rooconn/"
- no occurrence in "import" or "package" file headers
- class "onServerStreamReady" does not exists anymore, does not exist in file system at any place, no references

Clean and Build does not work. Restarting netbeans does not work.

How to resolve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

- Create a new project
- Add old project as a library
- Build
- Old project works again now